# Does Spring Data supports Calendar?

Tags: spring, datetime, spring-data

Does Spring Data supports operations not only with `Data` but with `Calendar` as well?

Can I do like this:

```
List<Vote> findByDeadlineBefore(Calendar now);
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly with Calendar, but yes, **you can do it with `Date`**. If you check the latest documentation:

[Spring Data JPA](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords)

you will see that `before` and `after` are supported keywords. For examples go to section:

> Table 4. Supported keywords inside method names

This function for example:
`findByStartDateAfter` translates to this JPQL:

```
where x.startDate > ?1
```